# Probability about candies.

Tags: probability

There are 2 yellow candies, 4 red candies and 6 blue candies. They are taken out one after the other. What's the probability that both yellow candies are taken out before any of the red ones?

My attempt:
The probability of a red is taken out in the first time is $\frac{1}{3}$, the probability it's taken in the second time is...

it requires a massive amount of calculation and I didn't continue (I will probably get it wrong anyway), am I overlooking something obvious?

Comment: You can disregard the blue candies.

Comment: This is a good problem to remind you that although you *can* have your sample space be incredibly detailed, having a more efficient choice for a sample space can make calculations much easier.  Yes, you could have treated every candy as distinct and had your sample space be all $12!$ arrangements of the distinct candies, but it is easier here to have our sample space consist only of the order in which the yellows appear with respect to the reds being only of size $15$.  The trick is in justifying to yourself why each of those $15$ results are equally likely so you can justify taking the ratio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disregard the blue candies since they have no effect on the relative order of the red and yellow candies.  Hence, we want to find the probability that the subsequence $YYRRRR$ occurs.

This is the probability that the yellow candies occupy the first two of the six positions in the subsequence, which is 
$$\frac{\dbinom{2}{2}}{\dbinom{6}{2}} = \frac{1}{15}$$
or, equivalently,
$$\frac{2}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{5} = \frac{1}{15}$$

Comment: How can you disregard the blue candies? Why won't it change the final probability? can you please explain this please?

Comment: As stated in the revised version of my answer, the presence or absence of the blue candies has no effect on the relative order of the red and yellow candies.

Comment: @abc... The blue candies will be taken out in some $6$ of the $12$ places in line; but *whatever* these happen to be, the yellow and red will occupy the *remaining* $6$ position in $\binom 62$ equally probable arrangements, only one from which has both yellow before all red.

Comment: @GrahamKemp OK I get it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

HINT: It is the probability of the sequence $YYR\ldots$. As you know from a comment, blue ones are meaningless.